# Add camera blur to AR application in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to blur the real world in my AR application behind the character which I am placing in the real world but don't really know how. I have tried using a blur shader on a material on an object but that was tricky to get placed behind the character?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ARCore with ARFoundation you can use `ARCameraBackground` component.

From the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@4.1/manual/index.html

> If you want the video feed from the device camera to show up as the rendered background of the scene at runtime, you need to add an ARCameraBackground component to a Camera. (...) If Use Custom Material is true, the ARCameraBackground uses the Material you specify for background rendering.

That means using custom material you can change the background of the camera.

I didn't test this, but if your shader will accept Texture property `_MainTex` you should get the current video feed in that shader. If that would not work, there is the section in the official documentation on how to copy video-feed to RenderTexture

Quoting:

> Copying the Camera Texture to a Render Texture when accessing the camera image on the GPU.

> Camera Textures are likely external Textures and might not last beyond a frame boundary. It can be useful to copy the Camera image to a Render Texture to persist it or process it further. The following code sets up a command buffer that will clear the render target and then perform a GPU copy or "blit" to a Render Texture of your choice immediately:

```
var commandBuffer = new CommandBuffer();
commandBuffer.name = "AR Camera Background Blit Pass";
var texture = !m_ArCameraBackground.material.HasProperty("_MainTex") ? null : m_ArCameraBackground.material.GetTexture("_MainTex");
Graphics.SetRenderTarget(renderTexture.colorBuffer, renderTexture.depthBuffer);
commandBuffer.ClearRenderTarget(true, false, Color.clear);
commandBuffer.Blit(texture, BuiltinRenderTextureType.CurrentActive, m_ArCameraBackground.material);
Graphics.ExecuteCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);
```

> Note: Graphics.SetRenderTarget will overwrite the current render target after executing the command buffer.